# Calling functions from helper file in casperjs javascript

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm trying to add a helpers file for functions in casperjs scripts to save repeating code in multiple scripts.

My initial script.js file is uses and calls the function below and works

```
function getTitles() {
  var titles = document.querySelectorAll('[itemprop="title"]');
  return [].map.call(titles, function (title) {
    return title.innerText;
  });
}

titles = this.evaluate(getTitles);
utils.dump(titles);
```

I have the following function in helpers.js

```
exports.getTitles = function (selector) {
  this.evaluate(function () {
    var titles = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return [].map.call(titles, function (title) {
      return title.innerText;
    });
  })
}
```

and try to call from script.js like this

```
titles = helpers.getTitles('[itemprop="title"]');
utils.dump(titles);
```

Other function in the helpers file are working so the code should be accessible to the script.

Can anybody advise where I'm going wrong.  Any help appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`exports.getTitles` looks like **CommonJS** syntax used by **Node.js**... The problem is that **CasperJS** is not a true Node module, so unless you are working with **SpookyJS**, this is not the standard way to manage modules with this library.

CasperJS is built on top of **PhantomJS** which provides a useful method called `injectJs` to inject external scripts. In your case, you could organize your code like so:

### Main script (*script.js*)

```
phantom.injectJs('helpers.js');

// ------------------------------

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function () {
  console.log(helpers.foo, helpers.bar());
});

casper.run();
```

### Shared variables and functions (*helpers.js*)

```
var helpers = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: function () {
    return 'Bar';
  }
};
```

If you run `casperjs script.js`, you should see `Foo Bar` in your terminal. Here `script.js` and `helpers.js` must be in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you.  This works in that it is reading the function from the other file, but only when the selector is hardcoded in to the helpers.js file in the getTitles function.  How can I pass the selector variable from script.js to helpers.js?

Comment: Using a parameter?